# slowcheetah How to remove element by it's child value ?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have XML that contains tables. I need to remove table with code B (There is only one B).

```
<Tables>
  <Table>
    <Name>My Name</Name>
    <Code>A</Code>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Name>His Name</Name>
    <Code>B</Code>
  </Table>
</Tables>
```

I tried this but it doesn't work..

```
<Tables xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
<Table xdt:Locator="XPath(//Tables/Table/Code[text()='B'])" xdt:Transform="Remove"/>
</Tables>
```

Need help.
Thanks.